# Gems not in Local Gems after bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, rbenv, rbenv-gemset

New machine. New rbenv install. New rbenv-gemset install. New ruby-2.0.0 install. New rails 4.0.0 app.

When I

```
$ bundle install
```

from the rails app directory, I get

```
Your bundle is complete!
It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
```

But, if I then

```
$ gem list
```

none of the gems that were supposedly installed show up.

I have run

```
$ rbenv rehash
```

Why could this be?

Additional info:

```
$ which bundle
/usr/local/var/rbenv/shims/bundle
$ rbenv which bundle
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/bundle
$ rbenv which ruby
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
$ rbenv gemset active
blog
$ which rails
/usr/local/var/rbenv/shims/rails
```

Comment: `gem list` does not show bundled gems that are installed in vendor. Try `bundle list` instead. `gem` != `bundle`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your default in this app is to install to `vendor/bundle`. You can tell this by `It was installed into ./vendor/bundle` text which appears after gems installation.

[Bundler documentation](http://bundler.io/v1.3/bundle_install.html) specifies that you have to pass `--system` to install in system location:

```
--system: Install to the system location ($BUNDLE_PATH or $GEM_HOME) even
          if the bundle was previously installed somewhere else for this
          application
```

EDIT: More explanation is that your ruby knows only about gems installed with --system option when not using `bundle exec`. You can see your gems from `vendor/bundle` or whatever path you've chosen by running `bundle exec gem list` or (as Casper noticed) `bundle list`. Now it is your choice whether you want your gems in system location or in application directory.

Comment: Thanks.

OK, so, assuming I want my gems in the application directory, how do I wire that up with the application's rbenv gemset?

Comment: If you have your gems only in scope of one application, why do you need gemset at all? I guess you can't use both gemset and `--path` option. Try `bundle --system` and then your gems should be in gemset.

Comment: `bundle list` lists all the gems installed for e.g. for capistrano deployed app. By default for capistrano deployed apps the gems gets installed under folder `/<rails_app_name>/shared/bundle/ruby`. Running `gem list` from `<rails_app_name>/current` folder like `<rails_app_name>/current$ gem list` just lists the globally installed gems. To view the list of gems installed for the application we should run `<rails_app_name>/current$ bundle list`.