# Rvm and gems, bundle show and gem list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

Im using RVM with ruby on rails, when I do `bundle install` it shows a whole bunch more gems than when I do `gem list`? Something to do with rvm and which path its using?

**bundle install**

```
mds@db1:~/staging$ bundle
Using rake (0.9.6) 
Using Ascii85 (1.0.1) 
Using Platform (0.4.0) 
Using open4 (1.3.0) 
Using POpen4 (0.1.4) 
Using activesupport (2.3.17) 
Using rack (1.1.6) 
Using actionpack (2.3.17) 
Using actionmailer (2.3.17) 
Using activerecord (2.3.17) 
Using activeresource (2.3.17) 
Using acts_as_audited (1.1.1) 
Using addressable (2.2.8) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Using gyoku (1.0.0) 
Using nokogiri (1.5.6) 
Using akami (1.2.0) 
Using ar-extensions (0.9.5) 
Using cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0) 
Using chunky_png (1.2.5) 
Using cocaine (0.2.1) 
Using coderay (1.0.9) 
Using fssm (0.2.9) 
Using sass (3.1.18) 
Using compass (0.12.1) 
Using daemons (1.1.9) 
Using warden (0.10.7) 
Using devise (1.0.6) 
Using fastimage (1.2.13) 
Using html_compressor (0.0.3) 
Using rubyzip (0.9.8)
more gems......
Your bundle is complete!
It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
```

**gem list**

```
mds@db1:~/staging$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.17)
actionpack (2.3.17)
activerecord (2.3.17)
activeresource (2.3.17)
activesupport (2.3.17)
bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.1)
daemon_controller (1.1.4)
fastthread (1.0.7)
passenger (3.0.19)
rack (1.5.2, 1.1.6)
rails (2.3.17)
rake (10.1.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.2.2)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
```

Answer (score 2):

this happens when you use `bundle install --deployment` or `bundle install --path=...`, it generates `.bundle/config` with something like this:

```
---
BUNDLE_FROZEN: '1'
BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/bundle
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: '1'
```

it could be done by one of you coworkers or the bundler/capistrano integration:

1. if it was your coworker then just remove and ignore it:

   ```
   rm -rf .bundle
   echo '.bundle' >> .gitignore
   ```
2. for capistrano [rvm-capistrano](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano) describes how to disable it => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano#disabling-bundle---deployment-when-using-gemsets

Answer (score 1):

before doing `gem list` make sure you use the application's gemset:

```
rvm use application_ruby@application_gemset
gem list
```

Be sure to replace `application_ruby` with your ruby version string and `application_gemset` to the gemset that is used by your rails application

Answer (score 1):

There is a hidden directory called .bundle in the root of your directory. Remove that, then run bundle again.

Answer (score 1):

According to [bundler documentation](http://bundler.io/v1.11/bundle_install.html) the current default, in ops case, may have been set to vendor/bundle, e.g. by a prior execution `bundle install --path vendor/bundle`:

> Further bundle commands or calls to Bundler.setup or Bundler.require
>   will remember this location

Also check contents of $BUNDLE_PATH which shows where it's installed. Note: It's also possible it was installed to vendor/bundle via the --deployment option. See [Deplyment mode](http://bundler.io/man/bundle-install.1.html#DEPLOYMENT-MODE) 3.

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17502450/2066936), `gem list` will show only the gems installed using the --system option (see accepted answer and Caspar comment); use `bundle list` instead, to show gems installed in the application directory, i.e. via `bundle install` (without the --system option).

Comment: `bundle list` was the answer to my quesiton.