# How do i deploy with Capistrano without bundleing to the .bundle folder?

Tags: ruby, rvm, capistrano

I was having this exact issue: [Rvm and gems, bundle show and gem list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810552/rvm-and-gems-bundle-show-and-gem-list)

I followed the advice of one of the answers and looked at the capistrano RVM docs (https://github.com/rvm/rvm-capistrano#disabling-bundle---deployment-when-using-gemsets)

So I added this to my staging.rb file:

```
set :bundle_dir, ''
set :bundle_flags, '--system --quiet'
```

On deploy [cap staging deploy] I get this error:

```
You have specified both a path to install your gems to,
as well as --system. Please choose.
```

I have not specified another path and am wondering what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Check whether .bundle exists on local machine and on server as well

Comment: It is created on the server only and is not in my local files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of `capistrano-bundler` you are using, but the latest does not use `:bundle_dir`. You want `:bundle_path` instead, like this:

```
set :bundle_path, nil
set :bundle_flags, '--system --quiet'
```