# How to list gems used in a rails 2.x application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have a Rails 2.x application, and when I am on the server that hosts the application how can I list the gems that it uses?

I started using rails in 3.x and I didn't realize there is no gemfile in rails 2.x

Comment: hmmm try checking in `config/environment.rb`?

Comment: There are probably some `config.gem` lines in the `config/environment.rb` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only place where listing of Gemfile can be is application.rb file in applications build in rails 2.x framework other than that there is no other place it can be defined.
One command that you can try is:

```
gem list
```

Comment: gem list command lists all installed gem packages on the system. To see all gem packages used in a Ruby on Rails application we can open the Gemfile file located in the root folder of the application or running the bundle list command in the root folder of the application.

Answer (score 2):

> How to list gems used in a rails 2.x application

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502373/gems-not-in-local-gems-after-bundle-install/17502450#17502450), `gem list` will show only the gems installed using the --system option (see accepted answer and Caspar comment); use `bundle list` instead, to show gems installed in the application directory

Comment: @Blankman Can you please tell me why my answer is not vote up or not corrected, I believe that my answer is correct